# Php looping foreach duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a thread table and a comment table. A thread can has many comments
When I do mysql query. It becomes duplicate thread because of many comments.
How to group the tid?

I tried foreach in php but still no idea.

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 110
            [title] => This is question
            [vid] => 175
            [yesno] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 110
            [title] => This is question
            [vid] => 179
            [yesno] => 0
        )
)
```

I actually want this

```
 Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 110
            [title] => This is question

            [0] => Array(
                         [vid] => 175
                         [yesno] => 1
                   )
            [1] => Array(
                         [vid] => 176
                         [yesno] => 0
                   )
        )

)
```

Comment: use `select distinct thread.tid, thread.title,...`

Comment: `GROUP BY` in your MySQL query.

Comment: `group by thread.tid` also works

Comment: If i use group by.  the vid will only show once but i have 2 vid belong to tid

Comment: what u need? post ur requirement

Comment: if you want to get all coments this is the right way or what do you want?

Comment: Please check again, i edited my question

Comment: using mysql or php? actually, its an very easy task with php

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query something like this

```
"SELECT ... FROM tablename GROUP BY thread.tid"
         ^ --- Field name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query='select distinct tid,title from thread order by tid';
$thread_id=mysql_query($query);
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($thread_id))
{
   $data[]=$result;
   $query1='select vid,yesno from comments where tid='.$result['tid'];
   $comment=mysql_query($query1);
   while($result1=mysql_fetch_assoc($comment))
   {
      $data['comments'][]=$result1;
   }
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: How about using 1 query?   because I using LEFT JOIN